# requestSingleInstanceLock returns error, preventing instance locking in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, electron

I get the error `ReferenceError: mainWindow is not defined` when I try to request single instance lock in ElectronJS app.

The documentation does not state anything regarding any requirement of this variable. However docs do show an example of the variable `myWindow`.

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question. **Don't** post code or error messages as images! Please hunt down the error and post a [mcve] so we can reproduce what you're experiencing. Also, the error message references one of your scripts. Please make sure to include that as well, if it isn't the main script. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I cannot share the code to the full app. Minimal reproducible example is the above underlined function call. The error dialog does not show the full error message and  the try-catch doesn't catch the error. Nor does the error appear when line 8 in the screenshot is commented out.

Comment: Again, we won't help you if you don't share the code to reproduce the problem. It's your responsibility to do debugging as far as you can get. Screenshots **aren't** MREs and neither is the snippet you have shown in the screenshot. Have you tried resizing the error dialog? Also, it seems to appear on a line 17, but not on line 8. The main process' console might show the full error message. However, as per [ask], please make sure to find the least amount of code that reliably throws the error message and post it here. Posting a complete app is *never* necessary and *always* frowned upon.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner A better MRE will come. Resizing the window did not work. Line 17 is completely irrelevant to line 8, that's what confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I ended up writing which is safe on both Windows and MacOS:

```
var fs = require('fs')

module.exports = class SingleInstance {
    constructor(){
        this.appName = app.name.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase()

        this.tmpPath = app.getPath('temp') + '\\' + this.appName + '\\'

        if (process.platform === 'darwin') this.tmpPath  = this.tmpPath.split('\\').join('/')

        if (!fs.existsSync(this.tmpPath)) fs.mkdirSync(this.tmpPath)

        this.lockFilePath = this.tmpPath + 'lock.txt'

        if (this.isSecondInstance()){
            process.exit()
        } else {
            this.updateLockFile()
        }
    }

    updateLockFile(){
        fs.writeFileSync(this.lockFilePath, process.pid.toString())
    }
    
    isSecondInstance(){
        try {
            var pid = fs.readFileSync(this.lockFilePath).toString()

            try {
                var isAlreadyRunning = process.kill(pid, 0)
                //app is the second instance. terminate.
                return true
            } catch(err) { }
        } catch(err) { }
    }
}
```